# Does Safari 2 support tabbed browsing?

Tags: safari, web-browsing, tabs

Does Safari 2 support tabbed browsing? What is the first version that supports this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a google search for [safari 2 tabbed browsing], yes.

Source: http://www.macnews.com/content/safari-beta-2-brings-tabbed-browsing-autofill-forms